# Erro na Paginação ao remover numero exibido no link

Tags: php, mysql, paginação

**A paginação funciona perfeitamente, porem quando faço o seguinte caso: troco de paginação tudo na boa, ela me da um parametro de url igual a: localhost/index.php?pagina=1 se eu removo o numero da paginação e deixo apenas o = ele me da um erro (Warning: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given ou seja no parametro  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado_players)){

```
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
$result_player = "SELECT * FROM player";
$resultado_player = mysqli_query($conn, $result_player);
$total_players = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_player);
$quantidade_pg = 3;
$num_pagina = ceil($total_players/$quantidade_pg);
$incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg;
$result_players = "SELECT * FROM player limit $incio, $quantidade_pg";
$resultado_players = mysqli_query($conn, $result_players);
$total_players = mysqli_num_rows($resultado_players);

$sqs = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id='1'");

$sql = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM config WHERE id='1'");

$sda = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqs);

$sdl = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql);
```

?>

```
                                            $lim = 1;
                                            $inicio = ((($pagina - $lim) > 1) ? $pagina - $lim : 1);
                                            $fim = ((($pagina+$lim) < $num_pagina) ? $pagina+$lim : $num_pagina);
                                            if($num_pagina > 1 && $pagina <= $num_pagina){
                                            }
                                        ?>
                                        <nav class="text-center">
                                            <ul class="pagination">
                                                <li>
                                                <?php
                                                    if($pagina_anterior != 0){ ?>
                                                    <a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_anterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
                                                    </a>
                                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-left"></i></span>
                                                <?php }  ?>
                                                </li>
                                                <?php 
                                                    for($i = $inicio; $i <= $fim; $i++){ ?>
                                                    <li><a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $i; ?>"><?php echo $i; ?></a></li>
                                                <?php } ?>
                                                <li>
                                                <?php
                                                    if($pagina_posterior <= $num_pagina){ ?>
                                                    <a href="index.php?pagina=<?php echo $pagina_posterior; ?>" aria-label="Previous">
                                                    <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
                                                </a>
                                                <?php }else{ ?>
                                                <span aria-hidden="true"><i class="fas fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
                                                <?php }  ?>
                                                </li>
                                            </ul>
                                        </nav>**
```

Comment: Não precisa editar a pergunta dizendo que foi resolvida. Só o fato de ter [aceitado uma resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) já indica que o problema foi resolvido.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pelo que parece se tu remover o valor do parâmetro página a tua variável estará vindo vazia, pois em $pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1; é validado se existe o parâmetro mas não é validado o que tem nele, ou seja, pagina=1 e pagina= vai cair no isset pois nos dois casos irá existir o parâmetro. Em $incio = ($quantidade_pg*$pagina)-$quantidade_pg; ele está multiplicando a $quantidade_pg por um valor teoricamente nulo que é o $pagina e por isso ao tentar fazer a páginação ele está estourando o erro no mysql.

o que pode ser feito é o seguinte:

```
$pagina = (isset($_GET['pagina']) && !empty($_GET['pagina']))? $_GET['pagina'] : 1;
```

No código acima é validado se o parâmetro página está vindo na URL e se ele não está vazio. Se as duas condições forem verdadeiras ele irá pegar a página que veio no parâmetro, caso contrário irá setar a página como 1 por default.

Comment: desculpa, possuo pouco conhecimento sobre o assunto, poderia me ajudar em relação a isto

Comment: @RafaelBarros atualizei a resposta.

Comment: muito obrigado, funcionou certinho, não possuo muito conhecimento sobre tal área, então acabo confuso...